# Scala's Partial Functions in Haskell

Tags: scala, haskell, partial-functions

Scala has a very nice support of partial functions, mainly because in Scala when you define a partial function it also defines an `isDefinedAt` function for it. And also Scala has `orElse` and `andThen` functions to work with partial functions.

Haskell does support partial functions by simply non-exhaustively defining a function (though they are strongly discouraged in Haskell community). But to define `isDefinedAt` function in general you have to use some sort of exception handling, which I'm not being able to figure out. Once `isDefinedAt` function is defined then it can be used to define `orElse` and `andThen` function is already there as `(.)`.

In short, I want to define a function,

```hs
isDefinedAt :: (a -> b) -> a -> Bool
isDefinedAt f x = -- returns True if f is defined at x else False
```

Can anyone please tell me how such a function can be written.

Note, I can define a function with signature

```hs
isDefinedAt :: (a -> b) -> a -> IO Bool
```

for generic `b`. But I want a function without IO in co-domain.

A nice article on Scala's Partial Functions is - [How to create and use partial functions in Scala By Alvin Alexander](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-define-use-partial-functions-in-scala-syntax-examples)

Comment: By 'defined' do you mean 'not `undefined`'? Why not just use `Maybe`?

Comment: It is, by design, not possible to catch exceptions in Haskell without using `IO`. As you say, partial functions are strongly discouraged; if you write a partial function you should consider your responsibility to make sure it will never actually be called outside of its domain. If that can't be guaranteed up front, you should make it explicit that the function can fail through a suitable result type.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I know and completely understand what you are saying, but still this negative attitude towards partial functions seem a bit dogmatic to me. There are good reasons to use partial functions, for example head and tail functions. And using Maybe in co-domain in many such cases doesn't seems honest, as when someone thinks of head function, s/he thinks of it as a function NOT defined on empty list, so I do want my program to crash if I ask her to compute 'head []' with the error saying it's not defined, preferably.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I recommend that, like in Scala, you use a separate type for partial functions.

```hs
import Control.Arrow
import Data.Maybe

type Partial = Kleisli Maybe

isDefinedAt :: Partial a b -> a -> Bool
isDefinedAt f x = isJust $ runKleisli f x
-- laziness should save some of the work, if possible

orElse :: Partial a b -> Partial a b -> Partial a b
orElse = (<+>)

andThen :: Partial a b -> Partial b c -> Partial a c
andThen = (>>>)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the suggestion. I'm accepting your answer as it's good enough for me, but I was thinking if there is a way to converting the non-exhaustively defined function (which, let's say, I already have in code and don't want to change) to a Partial. I can't seem to find one. And if there is no way then what's the reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your versions of `isDefinedAt` are not what Scala does (even in signature); it's very possible (though discouraged) for a `PartialFunction` to throw an exception when `isDefinedAt` is true. Or, when you define one explicitly (not using a literal), vice versa: `apply` doesn't have to throw when `isDefinedAt` is false, it's user responsibility not to call it then. So the direct equivalent would just be

```
data PartialFunction a b = PartialFunction { apply :: a -> b, isDefinedAt :: a -> Boolean }
```

which isn't particularly useful.

`apply` and `isDefinedAt` are only really linked in Scala for `PartialFunction` literals which requires compiler support:

> [A PartialFunction's value receives an additional isDefinedAt member, which is derived from the pattern match in the function literal, with each case's body being replaced by true, and an added default (if none was given) that evaluates to false.](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#translation)

You can emulate this by using Template Haskell, I believe, but I honestly think using the more Haskell-like approach as described in Daniel Wagner's answer is better. As he mentions, laziness helps.

Though it works even better if you make sure `runKleisli f x` is executed only once; optimizing cases where you have both `isDefinedAt` and `runKleisli` requires Common Subexpression Elimination, and the compiler is cautious about doing that, see [Under what circumstances could Common Subexpression Elimination affect the laziness of a Haskell program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694437/under-what-circumstances-could-common-subexpression-elimination-affect-the-lazin)

Comment: I think the OP is more interested in the properties of the `PartialFunction` *type* rather than the `PartialFunction` *literal*.

Comment: And it's an important property of `PartialFunction` type that `isDefinedAt` result value has no connection to whether `apply` will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (**DISCLAIMER**: I have not checked the laws of the relevant typeclasses, and the presence of a string in the constructor for the exception in `Alternative` makes me wonder if it is lawful). Scala's heterogeneous `andThen` is covered by `fmap`; its homogeneous `andThen` / `compose` are covered by the `>>>` / `<<<` from `Category`; `orElse` is covered by `<|>`; `lift` is `runToMaybe`.

However, without a deep compiler integration such as exists in Scala, the pattern incompleteness warnings will interact poorly with this. Haskell only has module-level pragmas for these things, and you won't want to just indiscriminately turn them off in any module where you declare inexhaustive functions, or you may get nasty surprises. Depending on your usecase, you may find optics more idiomatic and less problematic; you can have the boilerplate generated for you through Template Haskell.

(**Note**: I called it `Inexhaustive` because `PartialFunction` is something of a misnomer, in that it implies that `Function` is total. But Scala has no termination or positivity checkers, so the compiler is not actually able to talk about totality; so you get this weird situation where a function that is not a partial function is just a "regular" `Function`, whereas you should be able to call it a "total `Function`". The question here is not partially or totality, which is a broader idea, but inexhaustivity of pattern matches.)

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
module Inexhaustive
  ( Inexhaustive, inexhaustive
  , runToMaybe, isDefinedAt
  ) where

import Prelude hiding ((.), id)
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Exception
import Control.Category
import Data.Maybe
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)

newtype Inexhaustive a b = Inexhaustive (a -> b)

inexhaustive :: (a -> b) -> Inexhaustive a b
inexhaustive = Inexhaustive

runToMaybe :: Inexhaustive a b -> a -> Maybe b
runToMaybe (Inexhaustive f) x =
  let io = fmap Just $ evaluate $ f x
  in unsafePerformIO $ catch @PatternMatchFail io (\_ -> return Nothing)

isDefinedAt :: Inexhaustive a b -> a -> Bool
isDefinedAt f = isJust . runToMaybe f

instance Functor (Inexhaustive z) where
  fmap f (Inexhaustive g) = inexhaustive (f . g)

instance Applicative (Inexhaustive z) where
  pure x = inexhaustive (const x)
  (Inexhaustive zab) <*> (Inexhaustive za) = Inexhaustive (\z -> zab z $ za z)

instance Alternative (Inexhaustive z) where
  empty = inexhaustive (\_ -> throw $ PatternMatchFail "inexhaustive empty")
  f <|> g =
    inexhaustive $ \x ->
      case runToMaybe f x <|> runToMaybe g x of
        Just y -> y

instance Category Inexhaustive where
  id = inexhaustive id
  (Inexhaustive f) . (Inexhaustive g) = Inexhaustive (f . g)
```

Comment: You might also like [spoon](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/spoon-0.3.1/docs/Control-Spoon.html).